# cannot load data into custom collection view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parsing

I have a collection view thats off a github repository named "MEVHorizontalContacts". Now I'm trying to populate data from parse into each individual contact cell. The problem is that no data is being populated into each contact cell. And when I set my cell count to greater than 0 the app crashes. Here is the code. I need help loading the data into each collection view item.

```
 import UIKit
 import Parse

 class MevHorizontalContactsExample2: MEVHorizontalContactsExample1, MEVHorizontalContactsDataSource, MEVHorizontalContactsDelegate {

var FullNameArray = [String]()
var ProfileImageArray = [PFFile]()

var horizontalContacts: MEVHorizontalContacts!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.setupView()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupView() {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.horizontalContacts = MEVHorizontalContacts()
    self.horizontalContacts.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.horizontalContacts.dataSource = self
    self.horizontalContacts.delegate = self
    self.addSubview(self.horizontalContacts)
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[horizontalContacts]|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["horizontalContacts": self.horizontalContacts]))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[horizontalContacts]|", options: .alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: ["horizontalContacts": self.horizontalContacts]))
    loadMore()
}
// MARK: - MEVHorizontalContactsDataSource Methods

func numberOfContacts() -> Int {
    return FullNameArray.count
}

func numberOfItems(atContactIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        return 2
    case 1:
        return 3
    case 2:
        return 2
    case 3:
        return 4
    default:
        return 3
    }

}

// pagination
func loadMore() {

                // STEP 2. Find posts made by people appended to followArray
                let query = PFQuery(className: " CommercialUsers")
                query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
                query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        // clean up
                        self.FullNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.ProfileImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                        // find related objects
                        for object in objects! {
                            self.FullNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "FullName") as! String)

                        }

                    } else {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

}

func contact(at index: Int) -> MEVHorizontalContactsCell {
    var cell: MEVHorizontalContactsCell? = self.horizontalContacts.dequeueReusableContactCell(for: index)
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: self.getImageName(at: index))
    cell?.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell?.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell?.label?.text = self.getUserName(at: index)
    cell?.label?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(12.0))
    return cell!
}

func item(_ item: Int, atContactIndex index: Int) -> MEVHorizontalContactsCell {
    var image: UIImage?
    var labelText: String
    switch item {
    case 0:
        labelText = "Call"
        image = UIImage(named: "actionCall")
    case 1:
        labelText = "Email"
        image = UIImage(named: "actionEmail")
    case 2:
        labelText = "Message"
        image = UIImage(named: "actionMessage")
    default:
        labelText = "Call"
        image = UIImage(named: "actionCall")
    }

    var cell: MEVHorizontalContactsCell? = self.horizontalContacts.dequeueReusableItemCell(for: index)
    cell?.imageView?.image = image
    cell?.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(34 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(167 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(240 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1))
    cell?.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(34 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(167 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(240 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1)).cgColor
    cell?.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell?.label?.text = labelText
    cell?.label?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(10.0))
    return cell!
}

func horizontalContactsInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)
}

func horizontalContactsSpacing() -> Int {
    return 10
}

func contactSelected(at index: Int) {
    print("selectedAtContactIndex - index : %zu option : %zu ")
}

func item(_ item: Int, selectedAtContactIndex index: Int) {
    print("selectedAtContactIndex - index : \(index) option : \(item) ")
}
// MARK: - Generate Data Methods

func getUserName(at index: Int) -> String {
    var array: [Any] = ([FullNameArray] as NSArray) as! [Any]
    return array[index] as! String
}

func getImageName(at index: Int) -> String {
    var array: [Any] = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7", "image8", "image9", "image10", "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7", "image8", "image9", "image10", "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5", "image6", "image7", "image8", "image9", "image10"]
    return array[index] as! String
}
```

}

Comment: Where are all of the `collectionView` delegate and datasource methods? You're returning a cell outside of `cellForItemAt`, etc. Is this pseudo code or real?

Comment: this is a custom collection view. Its being called here

Comment: func getUserName(at index: Int) -> String {
    var array: [Any] = FullNameArray
    return array[index] as! String
}

Comment: and here cell?.label?.text = self.getUserName(at: index)

Comment: None of these methods will display content in a collectionView if there isn't a datasource and delegate for that in some view controller. Can you show the view controller or collectionViewController code that is utilizing this collectionView?

Comment: please click this link

Comment: https://github.com/manuelescrig/MEVHorizontalContacts/blob/master/MEVHorizontalContacts/Classes/MEVHorizontalContacts.m

Comment: if you look through the code on that page you will understand what I'm talking about

Comment: i converted MEVHorizontalContactsExample1.m to swift so please don't get confused. I just imported all the classes in my header.

Comment: the datasource and delegate are declared in the view controller I showed above. I edited it so you could see the full view controller

Comment: @garrettmurray what do you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

-You create an empty array

```
var FullNameArray = [String]()
```

-Then the collectionView asks for the info, but the array is empty and shows nothing.

-You ask for the information to Parse using the function "loadMore", but you never reload the collectionView!

-Since the call to Parse is async you need to reload the collectionView once you have the response.

Solution:

```
// pagination
func loadMore() {

                // STEP 2. Find posts made by people appended to followArray
                let query = PFQuery(className: " CommercialUsers")
                query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
                query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        // clean up
                        self.FullNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.ProfileImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                        // find related objects
                        for object in objects! {
                            self.FullNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "FullName") as! String)

                        }

                    //ADD THIS
                    self.horizontalContacts.reloadData()

                    } else {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })

}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: do you want to see a picture

Comment: what do you think

Comment: I cant find any other error, the FullNameArray is populated with data when the query answers?

Comment: The image could help

Comment: what image are you talking about

Comment: well the picture haha

Comment: when I change the numberofcontacts from fullnamearray.count to 1 I get this error.  fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Yes, because the FullNameArray is empty, so it will crash at: "func getUserName(at index: Int) -> String"

Comment: what do you think about my comment above

Comment: thats my problem. Its empty but its full in my server

Comment: what could be the problem. Do you have any idea or

Comment: Here -> let query = PFQuery(className: " CommercialUsers")

Comment: You class is " CommercialUsers" or "CommercialUsers"

Comment: what do I do with that

Comment: whats the difference

Comment: a space before the className, check your query, if it really is giving you results or there is an error on it

Comment: glad it helps you, you could mark the answer as correct to close the question

Answer (score 0):

For the table to load the data you need to return the correct number of cells (which will be more than 0). If you are retrieving data after the page loads then there is no data to load initially (which is why it crashes). The solution is simple. An array should hold all the data. It should be mutable and initialize empty. Return the array count for the amount of cells. Load the data and append the array. Then reload the table. The array should have the new correct count and the data should load.

Comment: but thats not happening. I'm retrieving zero information in the array

Comment: please look again. I did everything you said and I'm getting nothing again